# JavaScript - usar Array en función

Tags: javascript, array, function, funcion

Me he estado animando a esto de programar y al ver respuestas de este sitio al final he decidido registrarme y preguntar para formar parte de la comunidad. Expongo mi problema:

```js
var palabro=new Array();
palabro=elegirPalabra();
    
    document.getElementById("enviar").addEventListener('click',comprobar);
```

Todo lo anterior está en el ".onload" y la función "elegirPalabra();" devuelve un array y funciona. Entonces tengo un botón que al clickar llama a la función comprobar, pero no puedo usar de ninguna de las maneras ese array llamado "palabro" en la función.
He probado a enviar el array en el ".addEventListener('click', comprobar(palabro));" pero ninguna de las formas es posible.

Mi función "comprobar" es simple por ahora:

```js
function comprobar(){
alert(palabro);
}
```

¿Me podéis abrir los ojos y ver qué está fallando?

EDITO: Añado el codigo que tengo de la función elegirPalabra();

Muchísimas gracias por los comentarios voy a responder a masterguru y voy a poner la función "elegirPalabra()" que yo tengo.

```js
function elegirPalabra(){
    
    cantArrayPal=10;
    numArrayPal=9;
    var p=new Array(cantArrayPal);
    
    for(j=0;j<p.length;j++){
        p[j]=new Array(5);
    }
    
    p[0][0]="P";p[0][1]="I";p[0][2]="E";p[0][3]="Z";p[0][4]="A";
    p[1][0]="T";p[1][1]="O";p[1][2]="R";p[1][3]="T";p[1][4]="A";
    p[2][0]="T";p[2][1]="R";p[2][2]="O";p[2][3]="Z";p[2][4]="O";
    p[3][0]="A";p[3][1]="V";p[3][2]="E";p[3][3]="N";p[3][4]="A";
    p[4][0]="C";p[4][1]="O";p[4][2]="R";p[4][3]="T";p[4][4]="O";
    p[5][0]="C";p[5][1]="O";p[5][2]="R";p[5][3]="T";p[5][4]="E";
    p[6][0]="S";p[6][1]="O";p[6][2]="N";p[6][3]="D";p[6][4]="A";
    p[7][0]="P";p[7][1]="A";p[7][2]="S";p[7][3]="T";p[7][4]="A";
    p[8][0]="M";p[8][1]="O";p[8][2]="S";p[8][3]="C";p[8][4]="A";
    p[9][0]="S";p[9][1]="O";p[9][2]="R";p[9][3]="D";p[9][4]="O";
    
    ale=Math.floor((Math.random()*(numArrayPal-0+1))+0);
    return p[ale];
}
```

Parece una locura pero ayudo explicándo rápidamente: "cantArrayPal" la creo para añadir más fácilmente el número de palabras que tengo. "numArrayPal" la creo para no modificar el número aleatorio cuando añada más palabras.

Creo el array y luego creo más arrays internos tantos como la largaria del array "p", asigno la palabra por LETRAS de forma manual, convirtiéndolo en un array bidimensional. Pero luego con el número aleatorio devuelvo un array normal.

Igual está aquí el fallo pero he estado probando todo esto y funciona bien.

Comment: En mis pruebas tu código funciona. Solo que he tenido que crearme la funcion elegirPalabra porque no la has puesto en la pregunta.  Seguramente el fallo está allí, o en tu HTML... ¿puedes poner ambos cachos que faltan?

Comment: Aquí te dejo un snippet con tu código modificado (he agregado el html y la función elegirPalabra de forma simple) para que veas lo que digo en mi otro comentario:  https://jsfiddle.net/74qtdwo2/

Comment: Incorporando tu función me sigue funcionado bien. Puedes verlo aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/8hunvj25/  (seguramente la respuesta que te han dado es correcta, pues en esa web del `jsfiddle.net` lo que ves en la parte de javascript se carga todo como si fuera un `.onload`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si intentas usar `comprobar(palabro)`, estás llamando a la función antes de tiempo, lo que hará que se ejecute, si quieres pasar algún parámetro a un `EventListener` tendrás que usar una [función anónima](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function). Lo que debemos hacer para que el `EventListener` funcione, es pasarle una función válida, que no haya sido llamada, de esta manera, el navegador sabrá qué ejecutar, sin embargo, si la ejecutamos para pasarla como parámetro, el navegador interpreta que debe ejecutar lo que devolvió la función (`undefined`) y ya no ejecuta nada. Por otra parte, si `palabro` es un array y lo estás intentando imprimir, no uses `alert`, ten en cuenta los tipos de variable, `palabro` es un objeto con el constructor `Array`, lo que hace `alert` es convertir todo lo que le pasen a una cadena (`string`), y hacer `alert(palabro)` solamente devolverá `[object Array]`. Si quieres ver qué se le está pasando a la función, debes usar `console.log`. Además de esto, estás usando un array vacío, invocas al constructor `Array`, el cual te devolverá un array vacío si no le específicas el número de elementos, aunque aún así, si específicas el número de elementos (como parámetro) cuando invocas al constructor, todos estos serán vacíos.

```js
document.getElementById("enviar").addEventListener('click', function() { comprobar(palabro); })
```

Comment: Perdón por no saber moverme por el foro todavía. Acabo de probar lo de la "función anónima" y funciona perfecto.
Voy a dedicar un buen rato a estudiar esto porque lo he implementado sin entenderlo y eso no me gusta jaja.

Muchísimas gracias @Rodrigo Ramírez y masterguru

Comment: @Viral Es solamente teoría. Una función es una forma práctica de reutilizar código, puedes revisar la documentación de [`function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function), las funciones pueden recibir parámetros, los cuales van entre los paréntesis separados por comas y se anteponen al nombre de la función `nombre(param1, param2)`. Las funciones se definen como: `function nombre { /* contenido */ }`. Por este lado, una función anónima, se define "anónima" porque no tiene nombre, es una función que se usará y llamará una sola vez.